# Populating treeview from back, not getting children

Tags: extjs, recursion, tree, treeview

In the following function, I only get parent objects and not their children (or grandchildren) as intended:

```
function nest(n)
{
    for(var i=0;i<n.attributes.length;i++){
        var item = n.attributes[i];
        root.appendChild(item.data);
    }
}

nest(me);
```

If I use recursion like `root.appendChild(nest(item.data));` I get children and grandchildren, but not parents.

How can I get both parents and children?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle which includes your data set and demos this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a clear explanation in your question of what you currently have and what you really want, I'll take a shot.

It looks like you want to populate some tree structure, but that you're only getting some top-level nodes.  This makes sense, because you're always calling `root.appendChild`, so things are always getting added to the root node.

I am confused by your example recursive call `root.appendChild(nest(item.data))`.  Your `nest` function doesn't return anything, so passing it in as an argument to `appendChild` isn't doing anything useful.

You should probably design your function to accept as arguments both the current base node (to which you will add the next level of child nodes), and the collection of things that will be represented by those nodes.  Depending on your data structure, this would be something like:

```
function nest(base, items) {
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        var new_child = base.appendChild(item.data);
        nest(new_child, item.children);
    }
}
```

If you have a well-formed data structure that you want to load into an Ext tree, though, you should just be able to load your tree structure into a properly configured store and have your tree just magically work.  If you show us your data structure, you might get some help.